# Windows/Visual c++ | Weird behaviour of Struct in x64

Tags: c++, windows, cl.exe

I want to read the PE-Headers of an x86 executeable on windows.
To do that I use the standart stcructures given by the 'windows.h'.
('image' is in this example a char* to by mapped PE-Image)

```
int main()
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dosheader = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(image);
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32* ntheader = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32(DWORD(image) + dosheader->e_lfanew);
    std::cout << "breakpoint 1." << std::endl;
    ntheader->Signature;
    std::cout << "breakpoint 2." << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
breakpoint 1.
```

Conclusion:
Thn Program crashes when using a Variable of the Structure IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32.

**Now the weird thing**:
I compile with Visual c++ compiler (cl.exe), with 
'[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64''

But if I compile my code as x86 executeable, the Structure works just fine and both breakpoints get triggered.

The IMAGE_DOS_HEADER structure works just fine, so i cant make myself any sense out of it.

My Question is now: why does that happen? I mean the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 structure should be the same on both x64 and x86, isnt it?

Comment: Hint: DWORD = 4 bytes

Comment: I know that, but how would that help me?

Comment: You say that `image` is a `char*`, this means it is a pointer. On x86 Windows, pointers take 4 bytes. But on x64 Windows, pointers take 8 bytes. Now, when you cast this pointer type value to a `DWORD` type value, as you do in `DWORD(image)`, you take the lower 4 bytes of the value and throw away the higher 4 bytes. No wonder this doesn't do any good.

Comment: That makes Sence to me, thank you